# Is the set up of my Aptana server (Eclipse plugin/RoR development) correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

I can't get my Aptana server started. I installed the Eclipse plugin and added a new Aptana server using the Windwos tab. What do I have to the further to show my project on localhost:3000?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe more about your problem?

There are two ways to start server:
- In eclipse with Aptana plugin, click start server button in the right corner of Server view. 
- In cmd, browse to your project directory and type: `rails server`

Comment: Thx. This was really helpful. But my friends already solved it.